# Duplicates nodes not connected by edge in small networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a graph network of books using networkx.  In my sample case I have taken two books from my bookshelf and used an api to pull the 'similar books' from Goodreads.  The similar books are read into a dictionary d1, using the below code.  d1 looks like this:

```
 #use requests to get book details based on id
 id_lst=[3431,6900]
 print(id_lst)
 from goodreads import client
 gc = client.GoodreadsClient(api_key,api_secret)

 d1 = {}
 for id in id_lst[:2]:
     book = gc.book(id)
     similar = book.similar_books
     similar_small = similar[0:4]
     print(book)

test=similar[1]
#print(test)

d1.update({book:similar_small})

print(d1)

{The Five People You Meet in Heaven: [
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Harry Potter, #7), 
Lord of the Flies, 
A Wrinkle in Time (Time Quintet, #1), 
Speak], 
Tuesdays with Morrie: [
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Harry Potter, #7), 
Lord of the Flies, 
Speak, 
Anna Karenina]}
```

I then make this dictionary into an edgelist using the below code:

```
    output = []
    for key in d1:
        for i in d1[key]:
        output.append((key, i))
    print(output)
```

This returns this edgelist.

```
[(The Five People You Meet in Heaven, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Harry Potter, #7)), 
(The Five People You Meet in Heaven, Lord of the Flies), 
(The Five People You Meet in Heaven, A Wrinkle in Time (Time Quintet, #1)), 
(The Five People You Meet in Heaven, Speak), 
(Tuesdays with Morrie, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Harry Potter, #7)),
(Tuesdays with Morrie, Lord of the Flies), 
(Tuesdays with Morrie, Speak), 
(Tuesdays with Morrie, Anna Karenina)]
```

I then try and read this into networkx to build a graph.

```
    G = nx.from_edgelist(output)
```

This returns a graph with two distinct clusters that are not connected, despite for example 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (Harry Potter, #7))' appearing twice, so it should be connected to both 'The Five People You Meet in Heaven' and 'Tuesdays with Morrie'.

Am very new to both Python and graph networks in general, and am trying to build a small project myself as my organisation is starting to look at them and I want to build my understanding.

EDIT:  Added code that builds d1 dictionary
EDIT2:  This is the result I get wjhen I draw the graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlnG9.png)

EDIT3:  result of nx.draw(G)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMs4k.png)

EDIT4:  Final edit - all solved by converting the output of the api into a string...

```
#use requests to get book details based on id
id_lst=[3431,6900]
print(id_lst)
from goodreads import client
gc = client.GoodreadsClient(api_key,api_secret)
str_ls=[]
d1 = {}
for id in id_lst[:2]:
    book = gc.book(id)
    books = str(book)
    similar = book.similar_books
    similar_small = similar[0:4]
    for s in similar_small:
        str_b = str(s)
        str_ls.append(str_b)
    d1.update({books:str_ls})
```

Thanks everyone who helped!

Comment: can you easily include the code you're using to build the `d1` object? it looks different from the documentation example: `edgelist= [(0,1)]`

Comment: How are you checking that your graph has two clusters? I copied your code to Jupyter Notebook and it shows me one big cluster.

Comment: Please, show to us the result of `nx.draw(G)`. Looks like you use some kind of matplotlib example that works bad with non-directed graphs.

Comment: Hmmm, very strange. I use the exact code and have one cluster. Please, try `G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d1)`, and, if it will not help, write your networkx version: `nx.__version__`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this folks.    Have tried using dict_of_lists and I still get the same result.

Comment: Version of networkx is 2.2

Comment: Well... Your prints contains no `"` symbols in strings. Are they exists in your code? Are your string properly escaped?

Comment: This must be it.  the return from the goodreads api is a list and maybe I need to force them into strings explicitly.  Will mess around with that

Comment: Can you `print(G.edges())`?

Comment: Also, `print(G.nodes())`.  What I'm struggling with in reading your code is how on earth it is handling the fact that the names don't appear to be strings.  Are the edgelists really not containing strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a goodreads api key so I built the example below using letters to represent the same structure as your book data above.

just run:

```
import networkx as nx

d1 = {('a','c'),('a','d'),('a','e'),('a','f'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('b','f'),('b','g')}

G = nx.from_edgelist(G)

nx.draw(G)
```

and if things are working right you should see [image]

that would mean networkx is working right and the issue is with the data you're passing

Comment: Thanks - am thinking the same.  The return from the goodreads api is a list so maybe I need to force it into a string in some way.

Comment: nice, I think as @vurmux stated the `()` in the text string could be the problem if the code i posted works for you. If you can produce that graph image above you could accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After our conversation I suggest that the problem is in your book names that not escapes properly. It is the only thing that we do differently (because you pick it with API and we copy-paste it and escapes manually).